# How to paste a value into Java JOptionPane showInputDialog box other than typing

Tags: java, string, swing, joptionpane

I'm working on a Java program, I need a String input, right now I'm doing with the following code,

```
String inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the complete path of the file");

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User entered " + inputString);
```

It works,
But, since the path could be long, I was thinking **to get the location from windows file explorer and make a copy of it and paste it inside the input dialog box** other than typing the whole string.

I don't know how to do it, any suggestions will be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use [filechooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) ?